# Differences in __dict__ Availability for Methods Accessed through Instances vs. Classes

Tags: python-3.x

`Disclaimer:` Before asking this question, I've thoroughly searched Stack Overflow for similar inquiries. While I found several related questions, their answers either didn't fully address my specific query or I couldn't grasp how they related to my particular case. Therefore, I'm posting this question in hopes of receiving a more targeted and understandable explanation.

Why does a method call on an instance lack a **dict**, while the same method called on the class has the same as a function created by def or lambda?

As far as I understand, this is the reason why I cannot add an attribute to a method called on instance dynamically.

Consider the following example:

```py
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        print("Hello from method!")

# Add an attribute to the method object
MyClass.my_method.some_attribute = "This is an attribute"
print(MyClass.my_method.some_attribute) # This is an attribute

my_class = MyClass()
print(my_class.my_method.some_attribute)  # This is an attribute

print('__dict__' in dir(MyClass.my_method))  # True
print('__dict__' in dir(my_class.my_method))  # False

# AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'other_attribute'
my_class.my_method.other_attribute = 'Also this is an attribute'
```

In this scenario:

When accessing **dict** for MyClass.my_method, it returns True, indicating that the method object possesses a **dict**.
However, when accessing **dict** for my_class.my_method, it returns False, suggesting that the method object lacks a **dict**.
Why does a method object, when accessed via an instance, not have a **dict**, while the same method, when accessed via the class, does have one?

How does this relate to the inability to dynamically add attributes to the method when called on an instance, resulting in an AttributeError?